# Composite models (models within models), or manual foreign key associations between models?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have two models, and I want to "nest" one within the other. Is there a way to do this with Sencha Touch? My models look like this:

```
Ext.regModel('OuterModel', {
    fields: ['name']
});

var outerStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'OuterModel',
    data: [
        {name: 'item1'},
        {name: 'item2'}
    ]
});


Ext.regModel('InnerModel', {
    fields: ['a', 'b']
});
var innerStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'InnerModel',
    data: [
        {a: 1, b: 5},
        {a: 2, b: 5},
        {a: 3, b: 3}
    ]
});
```

Each `OuterModel` needs an associated `InnerModel`, and I would love to just be able to have a field that *was* an inner-model that I could create `Ext.List`s from. I could add `outerName` to `InnerModel` and query on `outerName`, but this feels sloppy, manually managing the association.

Is the manual solution my only option, or can I make a model a field of another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models can have associations with other Models via belongsTo and hasMany associations. For example, let's say we're writing a blog administration application which deals with Users, Posts and Comments. We can express the relationships between these models like this:

```
  Ext.regModel('Post', {
    fields: ['id', 'user_id'],

    belongsTo: 'User',
    hasMany  : {model: 'Comment', name: 'comments'}
 });

Ext.regModel('Comment', {
    fields: ['id', 'user_id', 'post_id'],

    belongsTo: 'Post'
 });

Ext.regModel('User', {
    fields: ['id'],

    hasMany: [
        'Post',
        {model: 'Comment', name: 'comments'}
    ]
 });
```

See the docs for [Ext.data.BelongsToAssociation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.data.BelongsToAssociation) and [Ext.data.HasManyAssociation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.data.HasManyAssociation) for details on the usage and configuration of associations. Note that associations can also be specified like this:

```
Ext.regModel('User', {
    fields: ['id'],

    associations: [
        {type: 'hasMany', model: 'Post',    name: 'posts'},
        {type: 'hasMany', model: 'Comment', name: 'comments'}
    ]
});
```