# Sencha Touch: Load Xml data from Data Store

Tags: javascript, xml, sencha-touch

I am having a difficult time trying to access xml nodes that are not part of the record.
I would like to get the Success and Price node values.

Thanks!

An example xml would look like this

```
<Response>
   <Success>true</Success>
   <Document>
      <DocumentHeaders>
         <Price>1.99</Price>
      </DocumentHeaders>
      <DocumentItems>
         <DocumentItem>
            <Name>Test 1</Name>
         </DocumentItem>
         <DocumentItem>
            <Name>Test 2</Name>
         </DocumentItem>
      </DocumentItems>
   </Document>
</Response>
```

My data store:

```
Ext.regModel('DocumentItems', {
   fields: [
       { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
   ]
});

Ext.regStore('MyStore', {
   model: 'DocumentItems',
   proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 'Service.asmx/Initialize',
      reader: {
         type: 'xml',
         record: 'DocumentItem',
         root: 'DocumentItems'
      }
   }   
});
```

Comment: You might try asking this on the extjs forums, or linking them here.

Comment: You also might check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604878/composite-models-models-within-models-or-manual-foreign-key-associations-betw) to see an example of creating a model with associations. You might be able to load a "Document" model that hasMany "DocumentItem" and "DocumentHeader". I'm not sure if the default XmlReader will handle this, but you can always extend it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this property to the reader   `successProperty: 'success'` like this

```
  reader: {
     type: 'xml',
     record: 'DocumentItem',
     root: 'DocumentItems',
     successProperty: 'success'
  }
```

And for the `price` property I don't think there is another way then to modify your model to contain that property.

Comment: Alternatively, is there no way to create a "Document" model that has both "DocumentItem" and "DocumentHeader"?

Comment: Yes of course but that's just more work. Here check the APIs to see how to extend the reader http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.XmlReader

Comment: I don't think there is. Only model with DocumentHeader and an array of DocumentItems

Comment: Honestly I knew how to get the success property, but I thought I would have to override everything to be able to have it work for both Success and Price.  The fact that I might have to do a second web call to get my data is definitely not ideal.

Comment: You don't need to make a second web call. Why don't you want to have a model with DocumentHeader and an array of DocumentItems? Check this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806063/sencha-touch-nested-loading-and-dataview It will be the same just the Location array will be DocumentItem array and you will access them like this record.data.DocumentItem[0] etc..